# Jquery mouseover triggering on child

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mouseover

I've read every post on stack on similar topics which there is many, but none seem to fixing the issue for me.

Basically, I have a ul of divs containing a single image, on hover I trigger a fade to 50% opacity. that works without an issue. now for one of the div's I have a second image, absolutely positioned in the center of the div. when I hover said div the mouseover is triggered, however when the pointer passes above the second image it re-triggers the event.

please find code below

JQuery

```
jQuery('.lighter').mouseover(function() {
    jQuery(this).fadeTo(200, 0.5);
});
jQuery('.lighter').mouseout(function() {
    jQuery(this).fadeTo(200, 1);
});
```

html

```
<ul class="home-three-columns">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="lighter">
                <img class="first" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/gift-finder.jpg') ?>" alt="" />
            </div>
        </a> 
    </li>
    <li style="position:relative;">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="lighter">
                <img class="mid" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/product-of-the-month.jpg') ?>" alt="" />
                <img class="prod-week" src="<?php echo (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(68, 86);?>" style="position:absolute; top:99px; left:89px;" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="lighter">
                <img class="last" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/in-the-press.jpg') ?>" alt="" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see it is the second li causing the issue once the pointer is over .prod-week, based on the search's i've done I have tried using

```
jQuery('.lighter').not('.prod-week').mouseover(function() {
        jQuery(this).fadeTo(200, 0.5);
    });
```

etc, to no effect.

if anyone could give insight or point out the obvious mistake i'm missing it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This (the second event) is a consequence of 'event bubbling' - you might want to look that up. Basically, events triggered on child elements (mid / prod-week) will 'bubble' up to parent elements (lighter). [I'd be happy to elaborate on that but I think a google search will cover your question]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter) and [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave).

```
$('.lighter').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).fadeTo(200, 0.5);
});
$('.lighter').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).fadeTo(200, 1);
});​
```

Or, [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) for short.

```
$('.lighter').hover(function(){
  $(this).fadeTo(200, 0.5);
}, function(){
  $(this).fadeTo(200, 1);
});​
```

Your actual solution using `.stop()` only make it unnoticeable for the eye but if you log the triggering of the function then you will see it keeps being the same.

[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/UzWmY/).

Comment: I had previously tried mouseenter and was having the same issue, tried the hover function and was receiving "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" maybe some side effect of the page primarily running prototype

Comment: @Xand94, or you have a typo ;)

Comment: seems that a stray character masquerading itself as white space had infiltrated my clipboard during the copy! it is now working very nicely. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

seem's that somehow adding a stop to the animation fixed the problem.

```
jQuery('.lighter').mouseover(function() {
    jQuery(this).stop().fadeTo(200, 0.5);
});
jQuery('.lighter').mouseout(function() {
    jQuery(this).stop().fadeTo(200, 1);
});
```

Not too sure how that fixes it, if anyone would like to comment!

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1805-jQuery-Events-MouseOver-MouseOut-vs-MouseEnter-MouseLeave.htm).  Mouseenter and Mouseleave are the recommended events to use.  (also, just a bit of advice for down the road.. i'm pretty sure nesting a div within an a tag is invalid html)

Comment: And, yes, mouseenter and mouseleave _will_ sidestep event bubbling. (that's their raison d'être in jQuery). And, yes, nesting a block-level element inside an inline element is invalid HTML.

Comment: see above RE mouseenter, in regards to the nesting, it's an internal only page (i've skipped a few validation rules along the way)